# android phonegap save canvas as base64 compatible with lower os

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

hi I am trying to get a canvas image and get the base64 and save it. I tried to use http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/html5-canvas-todataurl-support-for-android-devices-working-phonegap-2-2-0-plugin/ but i get a gray image instead of the canvas image that i created a black box inside the canvas.

[image]

this is the canvas

[image]

this is the img that gets the val.data returned by the plugin

the conversion codes are on there link the is probably an problem on the conversion but not sure what since there was no error on logcat.

any help would be very much appreciated, or if there is another way to do this would also be open to try other methods